# How To Pass Different Input To Quartz Job using Trigger's Job Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

If a user, enters his email address, then my application sends him a mail after every 24 hours, So I created A Job, and for each User, i create a new Trigger.

```
@Component
public class MailServiceTrigger {
    
    private final RandomNameGenerator randomNameGenerator;
    
    private final MailServiceJobDetails jobDetails;
    
    @Autowired
    public MailServiceTrigger(RandomNameGenerator randomNameGenerator,MailServiceJobDetails jobDetails) {
        super();
        this.randomNameGenerator = randomNameGenerator;
        this.jobDetails = jobDetails;
    }

    public Trigger generateTrigger(User user) {
        return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
               .withIdentity(randomNameGenerator.generate())
               .forJob(jobDetails.getJobDetail())
               .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 * * ? * *"))
               .usingJobData("email", user.getEmail())
               .usingJobData("fullName", user.getFullName())
               .usingJobData("verse",String.valueOf(user.incrementVerse()))
               .build();
    }

}
```

I want to send an incremented value to the Job every time this trigger executes
The incrementVerse() method increments the value after every call (second last line), the default value is 1, but it is incremented only once and i'm getting the value 2 each time the job executes

How can i send dynamic data to the job every time from the trigger

Comment: *FYI:* Cron `0 * * ? * *` means "at 0 seconds, all minutes, all hours, any day-of-month, all months, all day-of-weeks", i.e. **every minute**, which is certainly very different from the stated *"every 24 hours"* mentioned in the question.

Comment: Why don't you just add `.usingJobData("user", user)` and have the job calling the `getEmail()`, `getFullName()`, and `incrementVerse()` methods, which will have the intended side-effect you're asking for.

Comment: Actually I use the `withDescription` method to pass the json param to the Job.It is very convenient, but not officially recommended.

Comment: @Andreas for testing I have specified one minute, i will change that to 24 hours before deploying it, and we cannot send non-primitive data types (excluding String) to the Job using .usingJobData() method

Comment: Only the `JobDataMap` associated with the `JobDetail` can be updated, not the `JobDataMap` associated with the `Trigger`. See link to answer up top. See also [Quartz Examples - Example 4 - Job Parameters and Job State](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/examples/Example4.html).

Comment: As the javadoc of [`JobDataMap`](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/JobDataMap.html) says it: *"`JobDataMap` instances are stored once when the `Job` is added to a scheduler. They are also re-persisted after every execution of jobs annotated with `@PersistJobDataAfterExecution`."*